# Looking at protocols on non default ports in Microsoft Message Analyzer

Tags: networking, tcp

I have previously been using Microsoft Network Monitor. I'd like to migrate to Microsoft Message Analyzer but I cannot find out how to view network traffic as a certain protocol (in my case TDS, the protocol SQL Server uses) unless it has the default port. For TDS the default TCP port is 1433 however I need to be able to look at TDS traffic coming on different TCP ports.

It was possible to do this in Network Monitor by editing the switch statement in the TCP parser to add the ports I required along with 1433 and then rebuilding the parsers. In wireshark it's even simpler as you just select the traffic you want and say "View as TDS" however wireshark's TDS parsing is not as good as Microsoft's and we need the parsing to be as accurate as possible.

Does anyone know how to parse traffic as particular protocols if they are not on the default port in Message Analyzer?

Many thanks

Rob

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for anyone looking for it:

You can go to Tools -> Options -> Parsing

There you can select the parser TDS and you can add custom ports

Answer (score 0):

Quick update is jut to update default port for the protocol in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MessageAnalyzer\OPNAndConfiguration\OPNs\Infrastructure\IANA.opn

Though it will stop parsing default port :)